# How to increase limit of add to cart without using $config['sess_use_database'] in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter in my ecommerce website and using add to cart function, but i can only add four product at a time.
How do i increase a cookie value without using `$config['sess_use_database']` 
so i can add more then 4 product at a time.

Comment: what's the logic behind that, why you can add only 4 products? please be clear.

Comment: if at all possible do not store the products in the cookie or in the session. use a cart database table that stores the cart items. create a randomized user id for the shopping session. save that user id to the codeigniter session. when adding items to the cart table save along with the user id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you exceeded cookie size limit (CI sessions are stored as cookies).. Most browsers max size is around 4Kb.

Set `$config[‘sess_use_database’] = true` in your config.php

Don't forget to create the ci_sessions table (http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

It works for me and  I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: I am working with Oracle 11g and unable to add more than one item? is there any solution?